# Passing directory name from sys.argv in python

Tags: python, sys

Quick question on passing arugments from sys.  In the code below, I don't understand the data_dir = "."  This data_dir is used in another section to represent a file directory, but I don't understand the = "." piece.  I had thought sys.argv would only pass one arugment, the file name that could be usedin in the function main. Any help would be appreciated!

```
def main(name, data_dir ="."):
    resp = Respondents()
    resp.ReadRecords(data_dir)
    print 'Number of respondents', len(resp.records)

    preg = Pregnancies()
    preg.ReadRecords(data_dir)
    print 'Number of pregnancies', len(preg.records)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv)
```

Comment: `.` === current working directory.

Comment: `"."` used to refer current directory (it is Linux concept) and `".."`  for parent directory.  Try `cd .`   and `cd ..`  on your system.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I thought that one could use `.` and `..` on Win & Mac too.

Comment: @devnull yes I know it is valid in Mac, but I will give it a try in Win. Thanks!..

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Never mind, who uses the command line on Windows anyways?

Comment: @devnull yes I rarely used command line in window. In-fact I use window just bcz of MS-office :P

Answer (score 1):

The * before sys.argv causes the list to expand out into all the arguments of the function. So sys.argv[0] is passed to name, and if it exists, sys.argv[1] is passed to data_dir, overriding "."

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example helps in understanding how *sys.argv works. data_dir="." parameter of the main() function is actually a default parameter i.e if you don't pass a value for data_dir, python takes its value to be "." which stands for the current directory in UNIX.

```
>>> 
>>> def main(name, data_dir = "."):
...     print name
...     print data_dir
... 
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv
['']
>>> sys.argv[0] = "some_file_name"
>>> 
>>> main(*sys.argv)
some_file_name
.
>>> 
>>> sys.argv.append("my_data_dir")
>>> main(*sys.argv)
some_file_name
my_data_dir
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

"." is the defaut value for data_dir, it means the current directory which program runs.